# I need to obtain the coordinates (x,y) of the densest point of a dataframe

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics

I have a dataframe with coordinates (X, Y) and I need to get a list with the coordinates of the points with the highest density.

I was using the mean of the coordinates (X, Y) and calculating from that point the distance to all the other points, and then ordering them, but the average is not always in the densest point.
Using gaussian_kde I can visualize the densest points, but I do not know how to extract the points to a list.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pylab as plt 
import random
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
from scipy.spatial import distance

def closest_point(point, points):
    """ Find the nearest point. """
    return points[cdist([point], points).argmin()]

x = [random.randint(0, 100) for x in range(1, 51)]
y = [random.randint(0, 100) for x in range(1, 51)]
fr = pd.DataFrame({'x':x,'y':y})

mx = fr['x'].mean()
my = fr['y'].mean()
fr2 = pd.DataFrame({'x':[mx],'y':[my]})

fr['Punto'] =  [(x, y) for x,y in zip(fr['x'], fr['y'])]
fr2['Punto'] = [(x, y) for x,y in zip(fr2['x'], fr2['y'])]
fr2['Cercano'] = [closest_point(x, list(fr['Punto'])) for x in fr2['Punto']]

lista = fr['Punto'].tolist()
media = fr2['Punto'].tolist()

distancia_numpy =  distance.cdist(lista,media, 'euclidean')
distancia_lista = np.array(distancia_numpy).tolist()
distancia_serie = pd.Series(distancia_lista)
"""
we place a new column with the distance from the average point to the nearest point
"""
fr['Distancia'] = distancia_serie
ordenado = fr.sort_values('Distancia', ascending = True)

xy = np.vstack([x,y])
z = gaussian_kde(xy)(xy)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y, s=50, c=z, edgecolor='')
"""in red the mean of the points"""
ax.scatter(mx, my, s=100,c='red', edgecolor='')

plt.show()
print (ordenado)
```

the result should be a list or an ordered dataframe with the densest points first, in fact I get those results, but they are not correct since the average point is not located at the point of greatest density.
Any help is very welcome

Answer (score 1):

Thansk a lot!, this code get the job done!

```
point_gaus = pd.DataFrame({'x':x,'y':y,'gauss':list(z)})
point_gaus_order = point_gaus.sort_values('gauss', ascending = False)
point_gaus_order_10 = point_gaus_order[:10]
ax.scatter(point_gaus_order_10['x'],point_gaus_order_10['y'], s=25,c='red', edgecolor='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to sort points by the estimated pdf: using `z.evaluate(xy)` as the (reverse) sort key will give you the most likely point first.

Comment: can you explain me a little more... i can't found examples of how to use properly the evaluate method,

Comment: According to what you described, you need to sort points according to density, in descending order. You constructed z as the density estimate (KDE), so now z is your density. You need to evaluate it at your input points, and sort points by it. 

Evaluate documentation is here https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.evaluate.html#scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.evaluate

Comment: thanks you! your help put me in the right direction